Strange issue with exclude and include in tsconfig.json
I have strange issue. When I do
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/__tests__",
    "**/*.test.*",
    "**/server-handlers/**/*",
    "**/*.stories.*",
    "tmp/components/form-controls/company-search",
    "tmp/components/form-controls/address",
],
"extends": "./tsconfig.json",
"include": [
    "tmp/components/**/*",
]

Everything is right, address component is not included and not compiled.
But when I replace it by (specified only 1 subdirectory to be excluded)
    "tmp/components/form-controls/address/address-city"

the address-city is included. Why its happening?

The exclude only excludes files whose path exactly matches the exclusion pattern, so that's why you should use:
"tmp/components/form-controls/address/address-city/*"

or
"tmp/components/form-controls/address/**/*"

